# Clojure and WebSockets

Tags: clojure, websocket

I'd like to use Clojure on the back-end to host a server via http-kit (serving the purpose of Node.js) and I would like to be able to have socket-based communication between server and clientside js.  How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

The sample code from the [http-kit website](http://www.http-kit.org/channel.html) works nicely:

```
(defn handler [request]   (with-channel request channel
    (on-close channel (fn [status] (println "client close it" status)))
    (on-receive channel (fn [data] ;; echo it back
                          (send! channel data)))))

(run-server handler {:port 9090})
```

Put the run-server call inside a main function if you are not running from a REPL.

You can then access that websocket, just like you would do from nodejs.